# javascript filter by values

Tags: javascript, json, data-structures

Given an object of form listed below, what is best way to obtain keys that contain a particular value? For example in following structure, if we want all the objects that possess property1, we should get object1 and object2 as answer.
Or can this be stored in a specific type of data structure for quick retrieval? 
Looping over values of all objects in one approach. I am looking for something faster than that. Would appreciate suggestions.

```
{
      object1: [property1, property2, property3],
      object2: [property1],
      object3: [property2]
}
```

Comment: Trivial with looping over all properties and checking with indexOf if the value is contained in arrays. If so push key into result array. You can do it yourself, at least try it.

Comment: Time complexity in that case would be number of objects + number of keys. Any better approach for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a faster data structure for that purpose, then you could turn your object into an ES6 map, like this:

```js
// Sample object:
var obj = {
    key1: [1, 2, 3],
    key2: [1],
    key3: [2]
};

// Turn into map keyed by values
var m = Object.keys(obj).reduce( (m, key) => 
    obj[key].reduce( (m, v) => m.set(v, (m.get(v) || []).concat(key)), m ),
    new Map
);

// Example use of the map:
console.log('1 occurs in: ', m.get(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```js
x = {
      object1: ['property1', 'property2', 'property3'],
      object2: ['property1'],
      object3: ['property2']
}

z = Object.keys(x).filter(function(y)  {
  return x[y].indexOf('property1') !== -1
})
console.log(z)
```

This just loops, and filters each key in your object and then does an equality check on the array of values. Kinda

Answer (score 0):

```
var l = [];
var dict = {...}
for (var key in dict) {
   var obj = dict[key];
   if (obj.indexOf("property1") != -1) {
       l.push(obj);
   }
}

l // Here is the result
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `filter()` function over `Object.keys(data)` and check if each object contains the value. You can also `map()` the keys to the value itself if that's what you want.

```js
const data = {
  a: [1,2,3],
  b: [1],
  c: [2]
};

const searchValue = 1;

const keysWithValue = Object.keys(data).filter(key => data[key].includes(searchValue));

const objectsWithValue = keysWithValue.map(key => data[key]);

console.log(keysWithValue, objectsWithValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop through your array and test each time using this:

```
if(Obj.hasOwnProperty("<property name>")){
array.push(obj);
}
return array;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code, i think, it will help you:

```js
const list = {
      object1: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
      object2: ['a'],
      object3: ['c']
}

function getData(list, value){
  return Object.keys(list).filter( item => list[item].indexOf(value) !== -1)
}

getData(list, 'a');
```